# Way to test Metrics.Counter value as done with Aggregator

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

With [Aggregators being removed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-775) as of Beam 2, is there a preferred way to test `Counter` value, like I did with `Aggregators`:

```
assertThat(tester.getAggregatorValue(fn.success)).isEqualTo(1);
assertThat(tester.getAggregatorValue(fn.failure)).isEqualTo(0);
assertThat(tester.getAggregatorValue(fn.empty)).isEqualTo(0);
```

Where `tester` is an instance od `DoFnTester` class and `fn` instance of my `DoFn` implementation, with aggregators `success`, `failure` and `empty` being final package-private visible fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to a question asked on the user@beam.apache.org list recently.

The [answer there suggested installing](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/b1bee214cdb1d68d8fe80a46158cc48c4974e5a453a0ae69ae54a7c7@%3Cuser.beam.apache.org%3E) a `MetricsContainerImpl` before running the test, and interacting with that, like Beam does for its existing tests (eg., [LateDataDroppingDoFnRunnerTest](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/core-java/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/runners/core/LateDataDroppingDoFnRunnerTest.java#L61)).

They also encapsulated it in a `TestRule`:

```
@Rule TestMetrics metrics = new TestMetrics();

@Test
public void invalids() {
  final DoFnTester<InputT, OutputT> doFnTester =
    DoFnTester.of(fixture);
  doFnTester.processElement(input);

  assertThat(metrics,counterValue(fixture.ctr), is(1L));
}
```